# C - weird memory bug

Tags: c, memory

So I have this really weird problem. I have a Swap() function to swap 2 variables of any type:

```
int Swap(void *item1, void *item2, size_t size) {
    void *temp_tab;

    if (sizeof(item1) != sizeof(item2)) return 2;

    temp_tab = malloc(sizeof(item1) * size);

    if (NULL  == temp_tab) return 1;

    memcpy(temp_tab, item1, sizeof(item1));
    memcpy(item1, item2, sizeof(item2));
    memcpy(item2, temp_tab, sizeof(temp_tab));

    free(temp_tab);

    return 0;
}
```

And I'm using it in my main program like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a = 9;
    int b = 5;
    int c = 2;
    int d = 6;
    int result;

    printf("A: %d\nB: %d\nC: %d\nD: %d\n", a, b, c, d);

    result = Swap(&a, &b, sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n", result);

    printf("A: %d\nB: %d\nC: %d\nD: %d\n", a, b, c, d);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is the output:
A: 5
B: 9
C: 5
D: 6

Somehow my Swap() function is accessing my c variable - I assume it has something to do with memory violation, but I have no clue how to deal with this. Any help would be very appreciated.

PS: result = 0

Comment: It's not a weird problem, you are simply using `sizeof` incorrectly. Soon as you pass something through `void*` all information about the pointed-at type is lost to the compile. In addition, using `sizeof` on a pointer type gives the size of the _pointer_ not the pointed-at data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof` on a pointer returns the size of the *pointer*, not what it might point to. So the comparison `sizeof(item1) != sizeof(item2)` makes no sense as it will always be false.

And this `sizeof` of a pointer problem is the root cause of your problem: You allocate too much memory and always copy the size of a pointer instead of the size of the data (which will lead to *undefined behavior* if the size of a pointer is different from the actual size of the data).

You *have* the size of the data (in bytes) with the `size` argument. You need to use that for your allocation and copying:

```
temp_tab = malloc(size);

memcpy(temp_tab, item1, size);
memcpy(item1, item2, size);
memcpy(item2, temp_tab, size);
```

Comment: instead of 'You allocate to much' it shall be 'too much': double 'o'  :-)